# Remove text with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to remove text that is not wrapped in any tag using jQuery

```
<p>This is some text</p>

This is "unwrapped" text //to be removed

<span>some more text</span>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: All text is wrapped in some tag, even if it's <body> - do you mean within a specific container element?

Comment: +1 for <body>, thinking the same.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Using the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery):

```
$(elem)
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3; //Node.TEXT_NODE
  }).remove();
```

Comment: Yes, the `Node` constructor function is not mandated to be visible at `window` level, and `TEXT_NODE` would normally be found only on the prototype, not the constructor. The ‘correct’ way would be `this.nodeType==this.TEXT_NODE`, however even that still doesn't work on IE, so typically you have to define your own `var TEXT_NODE= 3;`.

Answer (score 8):

First, you can wrap them with dummy spans:

```
$("body").contents()
    .filter(function(){ return this.nodeType != 1; })
    .wrap("<span class='orphan'/>");
```

Now you can remove them easily:

```
$('span.orphan').remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping it in a DOM element would mean jQuery can find it:

eg:

```
var text = 'This is "unwrapped" text';

$("div:contains('" + text + "')").remove();
```

or just:

```
$('p').next().remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

fwiw..

```
<div class="parent-element">
<p>This is some text</p>
This is "unwrapped" text //to be removed
<span>some more text</span>
</div>
```

via CSS:

```
.parent-element { font-size: 0px; }
.parent-element p { font-size: 12px; }
.parent-element span { font-size: 14px; }
```

Comment: The OP is asking for a solution in jQuery. Your answer is not using jQuery.