# Removing text from inside a <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove text with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571076/remove-text-with-jquery)

I want to remove the text from a `div`, but that `div` contains other nodes.

If i use `$("#hwiTestimonial").text("");` it erases the `<br/>` and the `<div>` as well. How can I only specify to remove the text, without any nodes?

```
<div id="hwiTestimonial">
    " Bla bla" 
    <br/>
    <div>....</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) the [contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) of the element to leave only text nodes:

```
$("#hwiTestimonial").contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType === 3; // Text nodes only
}).remove();
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/78UEJ/).

Comment: great. Just what i was looking for. 14min and i'll accept your answer :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use any one of these

```
$("#hwiTestimonial")
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
}).remove();
```

or you can use this for old browser support also

```
$("#hwiTestimonial").contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType === 3; // Text nodes only
}).remove();
```