# Select prefix and suffix tags of html-element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, tree-traversal

the problem I am trying to solve is to select a certain prefix and suffix of a selected html-element. A small example should describe what I am trying to do. Lets say we have the following html source:

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="tutlogo">
    <a class="box" href="sql/default.asp" target="_top">
      <div class="image" style="background-color:#FF9900;"></div>
      <h1>SQL</h1>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tutbuttons">    
  <a class="btn" href="sql/default.asp" target="_top">SQL Tutorial</a>
  <a class="btn" href="sql/sql_quickref.asp" target="_top">SQL Reference</a>
</div>
<div class="box1">
  <div class="tutlogo">
    <a class="box" href="php/default.asp" target="_top">
      <div class="image" style="background-color:#41BC81;"></div>
      <h1>PHP</h1>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="tutbuttons">
    <a class="btn" href="php/default.asp" target="_top">PHP Tutorial</a>
    <a class="btn" href="php/php_ref_array.asp" target="_top">PHP Reference</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Say I have selected the `<h1>PHP</h1>` element. What I am trying to extract as the "prefix" of this element are the `n` html tags before the `<h1>` tag. Given that `n` is 5, then what I want to extract as the prefix is the sequence: `</div><div><a><div><div>`. Respectively I want to extract the 5 html tags following the `<h1>PHP</h1>` element as the suffix. In this example that would be: `</a></div><div><a></a>`.

I tried to use the  [tree traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) methods of jquery to get the job done but, this way I wasn't able to get the closing html tags. I also googled for a solution but couldn't find anything that fits my needs. Perhaps someone has already done this and can tell me how to extract the prefix, suffix tags or can point me into the right direction. Perhaps its really trivial and I am just thinking too complicated.

Anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's trivial, which should make you feel good about your previous efforts.

You'll probably need some tree traversal, regardless of how you end up doing it. I was building an automatic tooltip creation plugin the other day, so had this kind of stuff on my mind.

Here's what I hacked together - http://jsfiddle.net/naazkc1v/

It's not a finalized solution, but it works as is and might get you to what you need.

1. Define the element you want to grab the tags around `var initialEl = $("h1")[0]`
2. It navigates up the document tree, stopping if it encounters $('body'), $('html') or $(document)
3. It takes that root element and recursively removes all attributes on the html tags and empties the text nodes
4. It finds your original element's HTML inside its new stripped down HTML, returning you the strings before and after it.

#### Example

With this HTML

```
<div class="box1">
  <div class="tutlogo">
    <a class="box" href="php/default.asp" target="_top">
      <div class="image" style="background-color:#41BC81;"></div>
      <h1>PHP</h1>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="tutbuttons">
    <a class="btn" href="php/default.asp" target="_top">PHP Tutorial</a>
    <a class="btn" href="php/php_ref_array.asp" target="_top">PHP Reference</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The 3 console logs at the end will be

```
<div><a><div></div>
<h1>PHP</h1>
</a></div><div><a></a><a></a></div>
```

#### Problems compared to your desired solution:

It doesn't currently guarantee that there will be `n` tags both before and after the target. Writing the parser to strip extra tags should be easy. However, grabbing EXTRA tags if the root parent doesn't contain enough will require grabbing the siblings of our discovered root node, running this whole function on that sibling, and then parsing the necessary tags out of its returned value.

#### Resources

- [Remove all attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870441/remove-all-attributes)
- [Remove text with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571076/remove-text-with-jquery)

#### Full Javascript

```
$(function(){

    jQuery.fn.removeAttributes = function() {
      return this.each(function() {
        if (this.attributes){
            var attributes = $.map(this.attributes, function(item) {
              return item.name;
            });
            var img = $(this);
            $.each(attributes, function(i, item) {
              img.removeAttr(item);
            });
        }
      });
    }

    var initialEl = $("h1")[0],
        html = $("html")[0],
        body = $("body")[0],
        el = initialEl;

    function nodeInBody(node){
        return node.parentNode &&
               node.parentNode != document &&
               node.parentNode != html &&
               node.parentNode != body;
    }

    while ( nodeInBody(el) ){
        el = el.parentNode;
    }

    var $el = $(el),
        //This assumes there's only ONE text node within the original element
        //If you have any other elements inside the element you're targetting,
        //this will fail
        $initialTextNode = $(initialEl).contents()[0];

    function removeAttributesFromChildren(el){
        $(el).contents().each(function(i,el){
            // Emptying Text Nodes if they're not our saved one
            if ( el.nodeType == 3 && el !== $initialTextNode) el.nodeValue = "";
            //Call the jQuery plugin we defined earlier
            $(el).removeAttributes();
            // Call this function on the element
            removeAttributesFromChildren(el);
        });
    }

    removeAttributesFromChildren(el);

    var html = $(el).html(),
        initialElHTML = initialEl.outerHTML;

    var start = html.indexOf(initialElHTML);

    // If our original item's HTML is contained in the html string
    if ( start > -1 ){
        // Grab the strings before and after it
        var end = start+initialElHTML.length,
            before = html.substring(0,start),
            word = html.substring(start,end),
            after = html.substring(end);

            console.log(before);
            console.log(word);
            console.log(after);

    }

});
```