# Remove text between two html tags using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML :

```
<span>
<input type="text" value="0" size="10" class="element text currency" readonly="readonly" name="element_18_1" id="element_18_1"> .       
<label for="element_18_1">Dollars</label>
</span>
```

I would like to remove the dot between the input and the label tags using jQuery.

I tried this code with no result : `$('#element_18_1').contents(':gt(2)').remove();` Thanks

Comment: try `$('#element_24_1').parent().contents(':gt(2)').remove();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove text (without removing inner elements) from a parent element using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633610/how-to-remove-text-without-removing-inner-elements-from-a-parent-element-using)

Comment: What is #element_24_1? Btw, modified example from here: https://api.jquery.com/contents/ works in this case: https://jsfiddle.net/g1jcezup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, however always choose an easier way, a simpler way, a clan slate readable and understandable way, a pure JavaScript way.

```
element_18_1.nextSibling.data=" ";
```

```js
element_18_1.nextSibling.data=" ";
```

```html
<span>
<input type="text" value="0" size="10" class="element text currency" readonly="readonly" name="element_18_1" id="element_18_1"> .       
<label for="element_18_1">Dollars</label>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

This removes all texts which are not inside a tag (as element)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
current = $('#element_18_1');
siblings = $('#element_18_1').siblings();
parent = $('#element_18_1').parent();
$(parent).html('');
$(parent).append(current).append(siblings);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
<input type="text" value="0" size="10" class="element text currency" readonly="readonly" name="element_18_1" id="element_18_1"> .       
<label for="element_18_1">Dollars</label>
</span>
```

You can make it shorter by joining some lines. I tried to show it step by step

Comment: @BekimBacaj, All these are not for removing a dot.It removes all texts which are not inside a tag (as element). I thought it's better to put a solution for any same problem. That could be useful in future

Comment: No, you are destroying the DOM just so you could remove a stupid "dot".  It doesn't make a slightest difference how much text there is in between those two relevant elements - it could be whole a poem for that matter - the correct method doesn't change a single bit.  It is not only stupid thing to do what you did that but it's also evil, because these elements will not be accessible to other code and functions and will cause all sorts of unpredictable errors to other parts of the script - this is an example of how you should never do things.

Comment: @BekimBacaj. It seems you like the word 'stupid'. As I said, my solution is not only for this problem. Suppose this code: <span>
<input type="text" value="0" size="10" class="element text currency" readonly="readonly" name="element_18_1" id="element_18_1"> .a.as       
<label for="element_18_1">Dollars</label>hkhkj
<label for="element_18_1">Dollars</label>.sfsdfs
<label for="element_18_1">Dollars</label>y7898
</span>

Comment: Why would you, it doesn't change a thing! - Your code is an example of worst possible coding practice in history of the web, and it's not the only one I see around here. It's 'specimen' of how you should never ever do a DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)  and [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/), i.e.:

```js
var el1 = $("#element_18_1"), el2 = $("#element_18_1 + label"), contents = el1.parent().contents();
contents.slice(contents.index(el1) + 1, contents.index(el2)).remove();
el1.after(" ");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
<input type="text" value="0" size="10" class="element text currency" readonly="readonly" name="element_18_1" id="element_18_1"> .       
<label for="element_18_1">Dollars</label>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

[As stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571076/remove-text-with-jquery), I suggest to filter out the text node(s), and remove them:

```
$('span')
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3; //Node.TEXT_NODE
  }).remove();
```

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pka2rcvv/).

Answer (score 0):

This code is a bit crude but it should work

```
$("span:contains('.')").html($("span:contains('.')").html().replace('.',''));
```